# JMeter's WebDriver's Javascript Interpreter unable to access second tab window

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jmeter

I am trying to run a WebDriver Sampler with the following code:

```
var pkg = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium); //WebDriver classes
var support_ui = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait); //WebDriver classes
var wait = new support_ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 5000);

WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart(); //captures sampler's start time
WDS.sampleResult.getLatency();
WDS.log.info("Sample started");

// Navigate to home
...

// Login
...

// Navigate to Messages
var messagesButton = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('chat-button')); // saves the messages button into messagesButton
messagesButton.click(); // clicks the messages button which opens up link in a new tab
WDS.log.info("Clicked Messages Button");

var tabs = WDS.browser.getWindowHandles();
var tab = WDS.browser.getWindowHandle();

WDS.log.info("All Tabs: " + tabs);
WDS.log.info("Current Tab: " + tab);
WDS.log.info("Next Tab: " + tabs[tabs.size() - 1]);

WDS.browser.switchTo.window(tabs[tabs.size() - 1]);

// Load General Channel
var generalChannelButton = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.linkText('general')); // saves the general channels button into generalChannelButton
messagesButton.click(); // clicks the messages button

WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd();
```

In this, after I log the user in, I direct them to click on a messages button. When they click this button, a new tab opens up and runs an automated OAuth process. What I want the test to do is navigate to the new tab that was opened, and then wait for the OAuth to fully process and the final redirect to occur. Once that happens, I want to click on a button.

However, right now I am getting stuck when I go to move to the tab that opens via the messages button. Here is what gets printed out:

```
2019-08-13 15:17:15,480 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2019-08-13 15:17:15,484 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2019-08-13 15:17:15,488 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
2019-08-13 15:17:15,834 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group
2019-08-13 15:17:15,834 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group.
2019-08-13 15:17:15,834 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2019-08-13 15:17:15,834 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=1 delayedStart=false
2019-08-13 15:17:15,836 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2019-08-13 15:17:15,837 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2019-08-13 15:17:15,839 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
2019-08-13 15:17:17,755 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Sample started
2019-08-13 15:17:25,007 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Sample ended - navigated to yt-portal.raccoongang.com
2019-08-13 15:17:25,180 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Entered Username
2019-08-13 15:17:25,285 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Entered Password
2019-08-13 15:17:42,159 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Submitted Login
2019-08-13 15:17:42,303 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Clicked Messages Button
2019-08-13 15:17:42,314 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: All Tabs: [CDwindow-2071965AEF3647D3F81E3C45E722803F, CDwindow-680DEFAD39924A4A2FE9BF6C6CCF907F]
2019-08-13 15:17:42,315 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Current Tab: CDwindow-2071965AEF3647D3F81E3C45E722803F
2019-08-13 15:17:42,316 INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Next Tab: null
2019-08-13 15:17:42,317 ERROR c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: TypeError: WDS.browser.switchTo.window is not a function in <eval> at line number 39
2019-08-13 15:17:42,318 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-1
2019-08-13 15:17:42,318 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1
2019-08-13 15:17:42,543 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2019-08-13 15:17:42,544 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)
```

As you can see, `All Tabs` prints an array with two tabs, but when I try to access the tab at index 1, it prints out null...

How can I access the second tab and wait for it to load a certain redirect url before continuing on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the "javascript" interpreter doesn't interpret `getWindowHandles()` as an `Array` but rather a `Set`, even though when you print out the `typeof` of the result of `getWindowHandles()` it says `object`.

So, what you have to do is create an `Iterator` out of the `Set` and then iterate over it in a more Java-like way than a javascript-type way.

```
var tabs = WDS.browser.getWindowHandles();
var tabsIterator = tabs.iterator();
var tabsArr = [];
while(tabsIterator.hasNext()) {
    tabsArr.push(tabsIterator.next());
}
var chatTab = tabsArr[tabsArr.length - 1];
WDS.browser.switchTo().window(chatTab);
WDS.log.info("Navigated to Chat Tab");
```

Answer (score 0):

Read jmeter.log file more carefully:

```
TypeError: WDS.browser.switchTo.window is not a function in <eval> at line number 39
```

My expectation is that you need to replace this line:

```
WDS.browser.switchTo.window(tabs[tabs.size() - 1]);
```

with this one:

```
WDS.browser.switchTo().window(tabs[tabs.size() - 1]);
```

because [switchTo()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#switchTo--) is a function therefore it needs to have trailing parentheses.

More information: [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered/)

Comment: Read my question more carefully. I'm asking about why I can't access the elements in the array that `getWindowHandles` returns. Plus, I had seen some documentation that used `switchTo` instead of `switchTo()` so I tried it out. Anyways, turns out the "javascript" interpreter doesn't interpret `getWindowHandles()` as an array but rather a Set, even though when you print out the typeof of the result of `getWindowHandles` it says object. So, what you have to do is create an Iterator out of the Set and then iterate over it in a more Java-like way than a javascript type way.